# angular encode part of $scope to json

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm working with angular and have most of my api functioning, but I'm having trouble with a put function.  My server is hosted by an arduino and can't receive all the data sent by the json stringify.

How to make a JSON obj with only certain $scope data?

This is what I've got so far, with 'chanObj'.  The alert returns in some tests "undefined", and on other tests an empty object at the end of the scope.

```
  $scope.setpointClk = function(channel, setpoint) {
    var channels = JSON.stringify($scope.channels);         //original obj to big
    var chanObj = {setPoint : channel.setPoint, name : channel.name
      };                     //try to create a selected content obj
    alert(chanObj);
    service.putChannels(channels, function() {
      $scope.init();
    });
  }

channels: [{name: null, canal: "0", status: false, temperature: 19.94, setPoint: 0, permission: false,…},…]
0: {name: null, canal: "0", status: false, temperature: 19.94, setPoint: 0, permission: false,…}
1: {name: null, canal: "1", status: false, temperature: 20.37, setPoint: 5, permission: false,…}
2: {name: null, canal: "2", status: false, temperature: 0, setPoint: 5, permission: false, percentOut: 0}
3: {name: null, canal: "3", status: false, temperature: 0, setPoint: 5, permission: false, percentOut: 0}
4: {name: null, canal: "4", status: false, temperature: 19.94, setPoint: 5, permission: false,…}
5: {name: null, canal: "5", status: false, temperature: 19.87, setPoint: 5, permission: false,…}
6: {name: null, canal: "6", status: false, temperature: 19.98, setPoint: 5, permission: false,…}
7: {name: null, canal: "7", status: false, temperature: 19.96, setPoint: 5, permission: false,…}
8: {name: null, canal: "8", status: false, temperature: -50, setPoint: 5, permission: false,…}
9: {name: null, canal: "9", status: false, temperature: -50, setPoint: 5, permission: false,…}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your `chanObj` without first calling the `JSON.stringify` function. Because that would convert your `$scope.channels` into a string.

E.g. on how to create your `chanObj` with specific properties from your `$scope.channels`

```
$scope.setpointClk = function(channel, setpoint) {
    ...
    var chanObj = {
        setPoint: $scope.channels.setPoint,
        name: $scope.channels.name
    };
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Nitrof, It's an object, don't `alert` it, use `console.log(chanObj)`, add see it from the browser dev tool console log

Comment: still return: Object {setPoint: undefined, name: undefined}

Comment: found it ! I have to inject $scope into the function      $scope.setpointClk = function($scope, channel) {
          var chanObj = {setPoint : $scope.setPoint, name : $scope.name};

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new object and pass that to the `put` call, like you have with the `chanObj` object, pass that to the put.

If you have a lot of properties to maintain, you could do something like this:

```
var propertiesToCopy = ["setPoint", "name", "foo", "bar"],
   cutdownVersion = {};

for(var key in propertiesToCopy) {
    cutdownVersion[key] = channels[key];
}
```

Then pass the `cutdownVersion` object to the put call.